# Want to know commands (codes) for following formatting tasks

Tags: support, inquiry

Want to know commands (codes) for following formatting tasks.

1. Degree Centigrade.
2. Subscripts and superscripts like CO2, 14N , (6C13)6H12O6.
3. Greek letters.
4. a portion of text, with special characters like stars, less-than, greater-than etc, that would not considered as a part of command (like nowiki command in wikipedia).
5. Displaying more-than 1 space-bars between 2 letters.

Also want to know, what-type of programming language? Surely it is not Wikicode. Is there any more-detail guidelines to handle this code?

Look how strange things a user has done on this website. [Stack Exchange experimentation sandbox](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/654/stack-exchange-experimentation-sandbox) A big salute to that user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to do what you want: [HTML Entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) and [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org). You can use HTML entities for characters like:

- ° `&deg;`
- α `&alpha;`
- Α `&Alpha;` (note the capitalization)
- λ `&lambda;`

etc.

---

MathJax is basically a JavaScript implementation of [$\LaTeX$](https://www.latex-project.org/) (that's `$\LaTeX$` for those who are taking notes), a text formatting language. $\LaTeX$ itself is gigantic, so MathJax aims to implement a limited subset (still quite large) related to mathematics and other technical disciplines like chemistry. Rather than repeat a whole bunch of data presented elsewhere, here are some links:

- [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) from the Math.SE meta site.
- [How can I format math/chemistry expressions here?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) from the Chemistry.SE meta site.
- [An online $\LaTeX$ Equation Editor](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php)

Finally, one quick hint that'll help you learn - if you come across something formatted in $\LaTeX$ on a Stack Exchange site (and possibly elsewhere online where they're using MathJax), just right-click on it and select **`Show Math As → TeX Commands`** and a popup will open showing the commands used, instead of having to edit the question/answer to see the source. Please also note you cannot use HTML Entities in MathJax, but there are symbols/commands for everything you'll need already built-in.

There are *many* $\LaTeX$/MathJax resources online, so if you get stuck, just Google.

Comment: Sometimes putting a star marks disrupt bold or italic portion.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused You can always use underscores to indicate bold and italic formatting - __this is bold__ (`__this is bold__`), _this is italic_ (`_this is italic_`), __this is bold with a star*__ (`__this is bold with a star*__`).

Answer (score 2):

I've found following things useful.

**1. As a general-purpose, rapid, short command for subscript and superscript:**

`<sub>subscript</sub>` and `<sup>superscript</sup>` in the edit field; gives rise to respectively <sub>subscript</sub> and <sup>superscript</sup> .

So; for example;

- to write Cl<sub>2</sub> ; type `Cl<sub>2</sub>` .
- To write 2<sup>3</sup> ; type `2<sup>3</sup>`
- To write <sub>6</sub>C<sup>12</sup> or <sup>12</sup><sub>6</sub>C ; respectively type  `<sub>6</sub>C<sup>12</sup>` or `<sup>12</sup><sub>6</sub>C`.
- To write <sup>12</sup>C<sub>6</sub>H<sub>12</sub>O<sub>6</sub> or  <sup>13</sup>C<sup>*</sup><sub>6</sub>H<sub>12</sub>O<sub>6</sub>, respectively;    type  `<sup>12</sup>C<sub>6</sub>H<sub>12</sub>O<sub>6</sub>` or `<sup>13</sup>C<sup>*</sup><sub>6</sub>H<sub>12</sub>O<sub>6</sub>`.

> Source and Courtesy: User @Terdon.

---

**2. To type something that will not be treated as command:**

there are 2 ways:

- 2. A. 4-successive space bars before the text.

But that adds a horizontal scroll-bar.

- 2. B. Quoting the text by covering it inside *2 [backtick](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Backtick) marks*. This could be done inside sentence;

> Source: seen while trying to understand the tools at visual edit toolbar.

---

- *P.S. At [help page](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help) there is an article about correct [formatting](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). Beginners need to go through it. I didn't knew about it and I took many days to search it out.*
- *There is also a page on [comment-formatting](https://biology.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)*