# How to properly hyperlink in comments the hyperlinks that contains bracket?

Tags: support, markdown

To cite hyperlinks in comment; I use the command format:

`Here's an inline link to [Google](http://www.google.com/).`,
out of [from total 3 formats](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

I've experienced, if the link-address being cited, itself contains a pair of first bracket, it gives rise to a strange situation.

screenshot-1

[image: bug example-1]

( [comment permalink](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/7932/why-are-there-no-wheeled-animals/30947#comment96120_30947) )

[image: bug example 2]

( [comment permalink](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/54332/which-fish-is-this#comment95742_54332) )

So, my question is;  *Is there any way to code them properly?*

---

### P.S.

1. The bug not affecting the answering. It is only affecting the commenting.
2. I do not use later-2 commands for commenting because...

   I've tested the other 2 formats in commenting; but that doesn't work. such as :

`Here's a reference-style link to [Google][1].  [1]: http://www.google.com/` gives rise to

screenshot  - 3
[image: sandboxed]
( [comment example permalink](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/654/stack-exchange-experimentation-sandbox/3480#3480))

and

`Here's a very readable link to [Yahoo!][yahoo].  [yahoo]: http://www.yahoo.com/`

screenshot-4
[image]
( [comment example permalink](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/654/stack-exchange-experimentation-sandbox/3480#comment4341_3480)) ;

So seemingly the later-2 format not for use in comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parentheses in URL are not a problem: for example,
`[text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbel_(anatomy))` works fine in comments without any escaping. It doesn't work in yours because you typed something with a whitespace within the URL parentheses:

```
[text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbel_(anatomy) something)
```

which of course broke the syntax.

---

The inline style text is the only option for comments. When a character contained in the URL gets misinterpreted, escape it with a backslash `\`: for example, `\[` instead of `[`. But this doesn't seem to be necessary for parentheses and brackets.

Comment: [url with round parens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbel_(anatomy)) works correctly.

Comment: [text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbel_(anatomy))

Comment: [url with square brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbel_[anatomy]) also works (the URL is invalid, but that's a different thing).

Comment: Hmm it working correctly. Seemingly subconsciously I was typing a space bar between last-2 closing bracket